# Error when trying to open SQL Maintenance Plan - SSMS 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, maintenance

If I open SSMS on my client machine, connect to our SQL server, and try and open a maintenance plan on there, I get this error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management
>
> ### Studio
>
> Could not load file or assembly
>   'msddsp, Version=9.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.
>   (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design)
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

If i try the same thing directly on the server, nothing happens (no errors or anything)

Answer (score 2):

I had this error message whenever I opened a Maintenance Plan.

Was running:

- Windows Server 2008 SP2
- SQL Server 2008 R2 **10.50.1617.0**
- SQL Server Management Studio **10.50.1617.0**

I downloaded and installed SQL Server Management Studio SP1 ([SQLManagementStudio_xxx_ENU](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727)) - didn't even upgrade the server itself, and was able to open up Managment Plans after that. Now I have:

- SQL Server 2008 R2 **10.50.1617.0**
- SQL Server Management Studio **10.50.2500.0**

I noticed that after installing this, I have the correct version of `msddsp` installed into the GAC.

[image]

Otherwise, [maybe this will work for you](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/420a44b3-86ec-4aca-8165-cf5ed5e2d8d4)?:

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your machine is at the same SQL service pack level as the server.

Comment: how can i do this?
Is there a cmd i can run to see which version?

Comment: if you have the database server installed locally, connect to it and do select @@version; if you only have the client tools, run Management Studio and do Help / About, check the version there against the server's copy. I'll bet it's lower.

Answer (score 0):

The (to a beginner) oh so alluring Maintenance Plans actually use a completely different component (SQL Server Integration Services, **SSIS**) to package and execute the plans.

This means that the SSIS and MSSQL installations used to *create* such plans must match the versions of the SSIS and MSSQL installations that *execute* them - yes, MSSQL and SSIS are two different programs.

After having run into this utter failure cr*p multiple times on both production and testing servers, I have ditched it altogether and am now using efficient, simple to use, and completeley controlled SQL Agent jobs.